# many commandName for one form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page jsp where i will use many attributes from differents POJO Classes so I need to use two commandName in the form.
It's possible to user multiple @ModelAttribute in the controller so what's the point if multiple commandName is not working ??

For example I want to insert an information, name and function, name is an attribute in class Agent and function is an attribute in class Activity ? what should I do?

### The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fiche_service",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView Fiche_service(@ModelAttribute Activite activitey,@ModelAttribute Etablissement etabl,ModelMap model) {
        Agent ag = new Agent();
        return new ModelAndView("FicheService","agent",ag);

    }
```

### The form

```
<form:form
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajouter_activite"
    method="post" commandName="activity" commandName="etabl">

  <table id="tabmenu">
     <tr>
         <td>Fonction :</td>
         <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="fonction"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Nom d'établissement :</td>
         <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="noml"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Ville :</td>
         <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="villel"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Délégation :</td>
         <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="cd_reg"</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Date début :</td>
         <td><form:input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="" path="dateAffect"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Date fin :</td>
         <td><form:input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="" path="dateAffect_etab"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"
                    type="submit" value="Créer" /></td>
         <td><input class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"
                    type="reset" value="Initialiser" /></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form:form>
```

The Exception:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - /WEB-INF/pages/FicheService.jsp (line: 397, column: 64) Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element
```

line 397 ==>

```
method="post" commandName="activity" commandName="etabl">
```

Comment: Have you tried it, before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/about "Get answers to practical, detailed questions"

Comment: Yes ! I tried but it's not working. i ask if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Please post what you have tryed: (jsp and controller) as well as explain what exactly does not work. -- Because I expect that there is a way to get it running.

Comment: Ok I edit my question, see the code above

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is impossible to have multiple `commandName` attributes with a `springform:form` tag.

(The implementation `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag` has only a single field to hold this value).

The easiest solution (that defently works) would be using a wrapper command objects, that has to fields.

```
public class CombinedCommand() {
    Activity activity;
    Etabl etabl;
    //Getter and setter
}
```

jsp:

```
<form:form
  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajouter_activite"
  method="post" commandName="combinedCommand"">

  ...
  <form:input type="text"path="activity.x"/>
  ...
  <form:input type="text"path="etabl.y"/>
  ...
</form:form>
```