# Spring MVC: Multiple Models in A form: Binding problems and blank screen

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jspx

I want combine 2 model(users and userData) for get Request Params but as a result i saw a blank screen. what is problem in my code?

Register object is a ModelAttribute

users and userData models have some fields.

Data Models

```
public class Register {
    private Users users;
    private UserData userData;
//getters and setters
}
```

register.jspx

```
<form:form action="register" method="post" commandName="register">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="span12">
                    <legend>Sign Up as a Merchant</legend>
                </div>
                <form:input type="hidden" path="enabled" value="true"/>
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="control-group" id="usernameCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="username" path="users.username"/>
                            <form:errors path="users.username"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" id="passwordCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>

                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="password" class="input-xlarge" id="password" path="users.password"/>
                            <form:errors path="users.password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" id="confirmCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="confirm">Confirm</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="password" class="input-xlarge" id="confirm" name="confirm"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" id="emailCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="email" path="userData.email"/>
                            <form:errors path="userData.email"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="control-group" id="nameCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" path="userData.name"/>
                            <form:errors path="userData.name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" id="surnameCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="surname">Surname</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="surname" path="userData.surname"/>
                            <form:errors path="userData.surname"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" id="IDNumberCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="streetAddress">Id Number</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="idNumber" path="userData.idNumber"/>
                            <form:errors path="userData.idNumber"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" id="FactoryCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="city">Factory</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:select path="userData.factory">
                                <form:options itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" items="${factory}" />
                            </form:select>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" id="IssueSectionCtl">
                        <label class="control-label" for="state">IssueSection</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <form:select path="userData.issueSection">
                                <form:options itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" items="${issueSection}" />
                            </form:select>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Register"/> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" class="btn btn-large ">Cancel</a>

                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form:form>
```

UsersController_Roo_Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html",value = "/register")
    public String UsersController.register(@ModelAttribute("register") Register register, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateRegisterForm(uiModel, register);
            return "userses/register";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        //users.setUserData(userData);
      register.getUsers().persist();
        return "redirect:/userses/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(register.getUsers().getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

@RequestMapping(params = "register", produces = "text/html")
    public String UsersController.registerForm(Model uiModel) {
        populateRegisterForm(uiModel, new Register());
        return "userses/register";
    }


void UsersController.populateRegisterForm(Model uiModel, Register register) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("factory", Factory.findAllFactorys());
        uiModel.addAttribute("issueSection", IssueSection.findAllIssueSections());
        uiModel.addAttribute("register",register);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using register.users and register.userData instead of calling directly users and userData?

Comment: in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712462/many-commandname-for-one-form-in-spring-mvc)  Did you say here shouldn't be that way? How to i can do that with directly user and userData objects?

Comment: @FıratGürsoy Please elaborate the Question .not able to understand your problem.

Comment: One thing I can see that is wrong is that your object has a property **users** whereas your form references **user**. (For instance user.password which should be user**s**.password) according to the code you posted.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks i updated this property but problem not solved.

Comment: @NikhilArora i updated question. Problem is "form does not appear" and hence is data not coming

Comment: @FıratGürsoy what does this mean?"I want combine 2 model(users and userData) for get Request Params but as a result i saw a blank screen"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved problem..

in

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Register"/> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

I converted `&nbsp;` to `&#160;`

and problem solved.